# How can I Set recieved inputStream value in a textView in android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to ESP-32 Module and transfer data between android device and module via bluetooth.But there is a problem, I can show recived data in Logcat but i can't assign that value to my Custom textView. And There's my code below. im keep trying to send just 'f' with module but it just shown up in logcat and `textViewInfo` still has its default value.
Thanks.

```
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
int bytes2 = 0;
InputStream dtr = null;
while (true) {
   try {
      dtr = mmSocket2.getInputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();}
      try {
         buffer2[bytes2] = (byte) dtr.read();
         String readMessage2;
         if (buffer2[bytes2] == '\n') {
            readMessage2 = new String(buffer2, 0, bytes2);
            Log.e("Arduino Message", readMessage2);
            textViewInfo.setText(readMessage2);
            bytes2 = 0;
            } else {
            bytes2++;}
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: `trying to send just 'f'` What would be f?

Comment: `I can show recived data in Logcat but i can't assign that value to my Custom textView. ` Well why not? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Please tell where your code is executed.

Comment: You need to debug properly. It is highly unlikely that you're able to show the data in logcat but not in textview. Please check your code again.